# Knockout Avoid ko.computed active listening

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel, observer-pattern

how can i avoid height [ ko.computed] repeatedly run when i put a mouse over ?
[ mouseAreHoverFotoBanner ]

When a read something from ui, all ko.computed are automatically executed...

Code sample [ js ]:

var ui = function () {

```
            var fotoBanner = {
                scale: scale,
                scaleIn: function () { scale(0.9); },
                scaleOut: function () { scale(scale(0)); },
                mouseAreHoverFotoBanner: mouseAreHoverFotoBanner,
                enableHoverFotoBanner: function () { ( (mouseAreHoverFotoBanner()) ? "" :mouseAreHoverFotoBanner(true)); },
                disabelHoverFotoBanner: function () { mouseAreHoverFotoBanner(false); },

                url: ko.observable("270829_184226781631642_1559736_n.jpg"),
                height: ko.computed(function () {
                    toastr.info((this.wd.height() * scale()) + "px");//debug
                    return (this.wd.height() * scale()) + "px";
                }, this)
            };

            return { fotoBanner: fotoBanner };
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

A computed will always automatically update, because it is a [Knockout observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).  To maintain full control of updating: you may use a normal JavaScript variable, calculated from the Knockout observables `wd.height()` and `scale()`.  As a normal JavaScript variable, your new variable (say, "`height`") can be updated only at the times you wish for it to update.

- For example:

  > var height = (this.wd.height() * scale()) + "px";
  >   var updateHeight = function () {
  >
  > }

Ways to update:

- Write a [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to update it after an amount of time you choose.  This can be put in a while loop for repeated updating at an interval you choose.
- Write an update function (say, `updateHeight()`) and call it every time height() or scale() changes.  This can be done by placing a `subscribe()` on `height()` and `scale()`:

  > ```
  > wd.height.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  >     updateHeight();
  > });
  > ```